# Reading and processing a PWM on AtTiny45

Tags: pwm, attiny

I have this question and I can't find answers!

I wanted to use an AtTiny45V (due to low voltage requirements, it will run at 1.8 volts) to read a PWM from an Arduino, and then process this information.

Explained better:

let's say, I hook up one pin of the AtTiny to an Arduino pin (named `connection`), and in the IDE I write:

```
AnalogWrite(connection,X)
```

I want the AtTiny to write high on a port based on the X value.

Example:

X = 20 writes high on AtTiny PB5

X = 25 writes high on AtTiny PB5 and PB3

etc...

So, basically I want to read the duty cycle from the Arduino PWM and let the AtTiny do something based on duty cycle value.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What is the switching frequency of your pwm? How fast do you want to respond?

Comment: I'll be using the default PWM frequency of Arduino (490Hz or 980Hz, pin-dependant). For the response time I don't need it to respond in real-time, but also not taking ages for responding!

Comment: Your question is confusing though. You say you want your secondary mcu (the attiny) to set a pin high when the primary mcu (arduino) sets a pin high, but then you go on to say you want to measure duty cycles. One is just mirroring a pin state, the other is measuring the pin state over time. The former is much easier because time isn't part of the equation.

Comment: @gregb212 I want to set a different pin high/low on the secondary mcu based on what duty cycle the primary mcu has in output: I'll define a protocol in which some duty cycles will be associated to a pin state change

Comment: No, he says for a different PWM value he will raise different pins.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov Exactly!

Comment: You could set up two ISRs.  One increases a counter every time the pin changes on the 45 (high-to-low or low-to-high), and the other when a timer (say Timer0) overflows.  When the timer overflows, you can have a function that turns on pins based on the counter value.

Comment: @calcium3000 your solution can measure frequency, but his frequency is constant. He needs to read the PWM value.

Comment: @Ghesio take a look at the AVR135 app note from Atmel - http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8014-Using-Timer-Capture-to-Measure-PWM-Duty-Cycle_ApplicationNote_AVR135.pdf

Comment: It can be used also on attiny? I'm fairly new to avr world

Comment: @Ghesio, don't know. I have never used an Atmel MCU. so far worked only on PICs. But IMHO you should get a timer, start it with interrupt on rising edge and then on falling edge another interrupt should read the timer count. Something like this, but because I'm not familiar with Atmel I cannot give a full answer.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov oops good catch!  I've been doing the latter -- measuring frequency -- in a current project so that's where my mind's been.  +1 to the Atmel link!

Comment: I got the feeling that PWM isn't the best "protocol" for transmitting data. Why not use UART (serial)?

Comment: @Gerben I need to implement this "protocol" because I have to drive 6 AtTiny, I know it's not so suitable, it's just a workaround

Comment: What kind of data do you need to transmit? If you just need to send a short number,  you could just send that number of pulses, with a quite period after it. Very easy to read, no ambiguous readings, as it doesn't rely on very precise timing, like PWM (where you might send `120`, but read `118` on the tiny, because of inaccuracies).

Comment: @Gerben That is not a problem, I have only 8 cases to choose (I have to switch 3 leds, basically I'm doing an RGB controller), so a big accuracy is not required (I could make in the if controlling on the input pin a +/-10 error tollerance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to read the duty cycle, just the time that the PWM signal is high. First wait for the input pin to go high, then start a timer, wait for the signal to go low again, and finally read the timer value. If other tasks need to be performed concurrently then use pin change interrupt to detect the high and low transitions.

If the ATtiny is running Arduino software then the solution is even easier - just use the [pulseIn()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PulseIn) function.

This technique works for all PWM values *except* 0 and 255. With these values the pin stays low or high permanently, so there are no transitions to time. The easiest way around this is to simply avoid transmitting 0 or 255.

Alternatively you could pass the PWM signal through an RC filter to produce a 'DC' voltage, then read it with the ADC. However this will slow the response time down, and the signal will produce intermediate values as it goes from one voltage to another. To get good resolution the RC filter would need to have a long time constant, and you might have to average several readings to get a stable value.

Comment: Well, thanks. I'll try this as soon as possible, it should work

Comment: It's working like a charm. I marked only now because I had to mill the board and solder everything! If someone is interested I'm documenting this "PWM controller", just contact me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to drive a digital output on the AtTiny45V based on the PWM value from your Arduino, right?

I would suggest to use a simple low-pass RC filter to extract the mean value from the PWM and read as an analog voltage in the AtTiny45V. As the frequency of your PWM is known, you can easily design your filter to extract the mean value of your signal.
Then, based on your PWM mean value, you can define which pin will be set.

Comment: The PWM frequency is very low - about 500Hz. The filter will have such a big R*C that he should read it analog once in a minute. Not a very good idea.

Comment: I don't think it's that big, assuming the 500Hz, set the filter to 250 Hz, choosing C = 0.1uF, then R = 6.2k, this will give a time constant of 0.0006s, so the rise time will be around 0,003s. Please, correct me if I'm wrong on this. I used this method once, but the PWM frequency was 5kHz and it was a long ago.

Comment: these values with a 5V 50% PWM at 500Hz give a triangular (sawtooth) waveform with Vmin=0.8V, Vmax=4.2V. - PSPICE simulation results, I'm not joking :) R*C needs to be much bigger.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov, You're absolutely right, I was thinking about a step input to the filter instead of a square wave. Thanks to clarify my proposition.